# How can i calculate the difference of two cells based on the values of a check-column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling with finding a way to calculate the difference between two cells, if a criteria is matched on a check-column that I have. to further explain this, i have the dataset as below:

[Example of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fun9n.png)

In this table, column A is where I have times in which a bus has performed a cycle, stopping at each bus stop. In column B I have distinguished between start of the cycle, half of the cycle and end of the cycle. In column C i want to calculate the full time in which a cycle is performed, in other words i want to calculate the difference between time (in column A) of the end of the cycle (when "End" in column B is met) and time of the start of the cycle (when "Start" in column B is met)

Please note that the number of stops is different from cycle to cycle as the bus does not always perform the same stops each cycle. Therefor this task becomes a bit complicated for me. And also the number of cycles is very large, that why I am trying to find an automated way to calculate the difference explained above based on the criteria that first parameter ofthe difference should be taken if "End" is met and second parameter should be taken if "Start" is met.

I have no clue on where to start with this, so until now i have gotten nowhere in trying a solution for myself.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Something like if(check col test is true, calculate difference, do or not something else)

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe a Index and match calculation.

```
 =(INDEX(Table1[Column1],MATCH(E10,Table1[Column2],0),1))-(INDEX(Table1[Column1],MATCH(E9,Table1[Column2],0),1))
```

[image]

Maybe SumIF?

```
 =SUMIF(Table1[Column2],E10,Table1[Column1])-SUMIF(Table1[Column2],E9,Table1[Column1])
```

[image]

Regardless the result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the time is sequential, I like `FILTER`.

Something like: `=IF(B2="stop", A2-MAX(FILTER(A$2:A2, B$2:B2="Start")), "")`

[image]

Here you filter the previous rows in the data frame (make sure you freeze the right cells!) to only show those that also have "Start" in the row, then select the largest one (the `MAX` function) from the filter to subtract from the current time. If the current row is not a "Stop", we elect to leave the cell blank.